# VBA macro to adjust certain row heights to some total pixel number?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of possible fund options on one sheet that looks up tickers for data on another input sheet. A macro then deletes out all the other options that aren't used. I'm trying to get a macro to then adjust the cell height of the remaining rows (this number may change each time the template is used) to a certain total number of pixels so it fills out empty space on the sheet that gets printed. I'm not sure how to go about. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that you can determine the height in pixels, but something like this will allow you to set the height of a row or rows.  Just set the start and end row in .Rows().

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:68").RowHeight = 19.5
```

If you calculate the amount of space to set the row height, you can set the height dynamically.

Comment: That's the thing, I won't know how tall each row needs to be until the unused rows are deleted. It could vary a lot. I was hoping there was a way to split out the total I need to the remaining rows.